# Ugly Numbers: A Rags-to-Riches Story

Tags: programming-challenge, f#, rags-to-riches

I stumbled upon [an unaswered question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33542/ugly-numbers-problem), which looked like a good fit for a functional programming language.

Here is the problem statement from [codeeval](https://www.codeeval.com/browse/42/):

> **UGLY NUMBERS**
>
> **CHALLENGE DESCRIPTION**:
>
> Credits: This challenge has appeared in a google competition before.
>
> Once upon a time in a strange situation, people called a number ugly
>   if it was divisible by any of the one-digit primes (2, 3, 5 or 7).
>   Thus, 14 is ugly, but 13 is fine. 39 is ugly, but 121 is not. Note
>   that 0 is ugly. Also note that negative numbers can also be ugly: -14
>   and -39 are examples of such numbers.
>
> One day on your free time, you are gazing at a string of digits,
>   something like:
>
> ```
> 123456
> ```
>
> You are amused by how many possibilities there are if you are
>   allowed to insert plus or minus signs between the digits. For example
>   you can make:
>
> ```
> 1 + 234 - 5 + 6 = 236
> ```
>
> which is ugly. Or
>
> ```
> 123 + 4 - 56 = 71
> ```
>
> which is not ugly.
>
> It is easy to count the number of different ways you can play with the
>   digits: Between each two adjacent digits you may choose put a plus
>   sign, a minus sign, or nothing. Therefore, if you start with \$D\$ digits
>   there are \$3^{D-1}\$ expressions you can make. Note that it is fine to
>   have leading zeros for a number. If the string is `01023`, then
>   `01023`, `0+1-02+3` and `01-023` are legal expressions.
>
> Your task is simple: Among the \$3^{D-1}\$ expressions, count how many of
>   them evaluate to an ugly number.
>
> **INPUT SAMPLE:**
>
> Your program should accept as its first argument a path to a filename.
>   Each line in this file is one test case. Each test case will be a
>   single line containing a non-empty string of decimal digits. The
>   string in each test case will be non-empty and will contain only
>   characters '0' through '9'. Each string is no more than 13 characters
>   long. E.g.
>
> ```
> 1
> 9
> 011
> 12345
> ```
>
> **OUTPUT SAMPLE:**
>
> Print out the number of expressions that evaluate to an ugly number
>   for each test case, each one on a new line. E.g.
>
> ```
> 0
> 1
> 6
> 64
> ```

And here is my solution (ignoring the part about reading from a file)

```
type Expression =
    | Plus of Expression * Expression
    | Minus of Expression * Expression
    | Leaf of int64

let rec eval = function
    | Plus (left, right) -> (eval left) + (eval right)
    | Minus (left, right) -> (eval left) - (eval right)
    | Leaf n -> n

let rec expressions (s : string) =
    seq {
        yield Leaf (Int64.Parse(s))
        let n = s.Length
        for i in 1 .. n - 1 do
            let leaf = Leaf (Int64.Parse(s.Substring(0, i)))
            for e in expressions(s.Substring(i, n - i)) do
                yield Plus (leaf, e)
                yield Minus (leaf, e)
    }

let rec isUgly (n : int64) : bool =
    if n < 0L then
        isUgly -n
    else
        n = 0L || n % 2L = 0L || n % 3L = 0L || n % 5L = 0L || n % 7L = 0L

let countUglyNumbers (s : string) =
    expressions s |> Seq.map eval |> Seq.filter isUgly |> Seq.length

for input in ["1"; "9"; "011"; "12345"; "123456"; "1234566543215"] do
    printfn "%d" <| countUglyNumbers input
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the purpose of the `Expression` type? Why doesn't `expressions` just return all the possible results?

This might be useful in other situations (like printing all the possibilities), but I don't see a reason for it here. Basically, it's an unnecessary level of abstraction.

---

```
if n < 0L then
    isUgly -n
else
    n = 0L || n % 2L = 0L || n % 3L = 0L || n % 5L = 0L || n % 7L = 0L
```

You don't need the special case for negative numbers, `%` works for them too.

Comment: Good point about Expression, I realised that soon after I posted :)